# "x0vncserver" cannot open display from a ssh connection

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, display, vnc

I have a computer with a broken screen, I try to connect to this computer via VNC. The good thing is that I can access this computer via SSH.
The bad thing is I can't open the display from the SSH connection, it seems like.

```bsh
➜  ~ who
vdegenne pts/0        2020-12-29 15:41 (10.44.0.99)
vdegenne :0           2020-12-29 15:33 (:0)
➜  ~ x0vncserver -display 0 -SecurityTypes=None
x0vncserver: unable to open display "0"
➜  ~ echo $DISPLAY
```

As you can see I am connected with the same user "vdegenne" one from the SSH session, one from the original connection (even though my laptop screen is broken I know what to type to log into my i3 session).

Is there a way to tell SSH which display to use during the session so I can (at least) start the VNC service?

Thanks

Comment: Try with `-display :0` (note the colon).